# Any English terms for ‘to change the part of speech (of a word) without applying modification’?

Tags: terminology, linguistics

Is there any appropriate English terminology for changing the part of speech (of a word) without applying any modification?

This is a concept including *verbing* (where the verb *verb* means "to use a word that is not conventionally used as a verb, typically a noun, as a verb").

Korean has a term [*Yeongbyeonhwa* (零變化, “zero-derivation”)](https://ko.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%98%81%EB%B3%80%ED%99%94) for it, but I'd like to know the English one.

Comment: Note that zero-derivation does not necessarily change the part of speech of the word in question. For example, deriving a causative verb from a ‘normal’ verb by adding a zero-suffix (very common in English, as part of [causative alternation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causative_alternation)) is a form of zero-derivation, but the resulting verb has the same part of speech as the input. I don’t know if that’s true of the Korean term as well.

Comment: "Verbing weirds language": http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25

Comment: 'Conversion' is the term used for changing a word's syntactic category without any change of form, for example the creation of the verb "humble" from the adjective "humble".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word is 'conversion'. The word was part of the required metalanguage for an English language class I undertook.

The OED gives the definition relevant to the usage as:

> *Grammar*. The use of one part of speech as another.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct name for it.